# R for loop on discontinuous numbers generate empty value

Tags: r

```
lst <- list()
for (i in c(2,3,4)){
    lst[[i]] <- i
}
lst
```

The output in my computer is:

```
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4
```

Why the list object "lst" have a key "1" with "NULL" value. What is the logic behind this?

Answer (score 1):

R lists do not support empty numerical indices. In other words, no indices can be "skipped", and must start at 1. If you start by inserting something at index 5, indices 1 through 4 will be filled in with NULL. If you want something more akin to a dictionary, which would get around this auto-filling behavior, you could try:

```
lst <- list()
for (i in c('2','3','4')){
    lst[[i]] <- as.numeric(i)
}
lst
```

This would then create a list with *character* indices '2', '3', and '4', and insert the corresponding numerical values. It's a confusing use case, but it does what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just be confused with list indexes and names.

Comment: Alternately, `DF = data.frame(idx = 2:4, val = 2:4)`, and then look up values like `DF$val[match(i, DF$idx)]`. Or with data.table `DT = data.table(idx = 2:4, val = 2:4, key="idx"); DT[.(i), val]`.